# Can we use same subscription in different Azure region

Tags: azure, subscription, azure-virtual-network

Can we use same subscription in different Azure region. I want to create different Virtual Networks in different region and design protocol to communicate these regions.

Regards
Abdul

Comment: yes subscriptions can be used for different regions.

Comment: Thanks Saher and please find detail answer from Henrik too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily use the same subscription to spin up resources in other regions in Azure.

What regions you can use depends on your subscription type though. If you use any of the [Azure credit offers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/offers/) you will find that certain offers has limits on the regions they can activate resources in.

I would recommend that you simply test by making a [resource group in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/cloud-adoption-guide/adoption-intro/azure-resource-access) in the region you want to test with, then create a new [Azure Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview) in that resource group (which will per default have the same region).

This shows you the regions available to you. Repeat for each region you want a network in.

If you wish to connect the Azure Virtual Networks in different regions with each other you can setup [Azure Virtual Network Peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview)

A little side note.
Not all types of resources are available in all regions. I would recommend checking what regions are available in the [Azure Region Map](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/regions/), then check the [Offers by Region page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/) to see if the product you want to use is available in your chosen region.